# Python, Merging rows with same value in one column

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
     ID         Class
      0           9
      1           8
      1           6
      2           6
      2           2
      3           15
      3           1
      3           8
```

What I would like to do is merging rows with same ID value in a way below:

```
    ID       Class1 Class2 Class3
    0           9
    1           8      6
    2           6      2
    3           15     1      8
```

So for each ID which exists more than once, I want to create new column(s) and move values from rows to those columns. What is the fastest way to do this? I tried using `groupby` but it didn't give me appriopate results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for new columns, reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and last rename columns by [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['ID', df.groupby('ID').cumcount()])['Class']
       .unstack()
       .add_prefix('Class')
       .reset_index()

print (df)
   ID  Class0  Class1  Class2
0   0     9.0     NaN     NaN
1   1     8.0     6.0     NaN
2   2     6.0     2.0     NaN
3   3    15.0     1.0     8.0
```

Another solution is create `list` per groups and then new `DataFrame` by constructor:

```
s = df.groupby('ID')['Class'].apply(list)
df = pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index)
       .add_prefix('Class')
       .reset_index()
print (df)
   ID  Class0  Class1  Class2
0   0       9     NaN     NaN
1   1       8     6.0     NaN
2   2       6     2.0     NaN
3   3      15     1.0     8.0
```

EDIT:

```
df = df.set_index('ID')
df1=pd.get_dummies(df['Class']).reindex(columns=range(17), fill_value=0).add_prefix('Class')
df1 = df1.groupby(level=0).max().reset_index()
print (df1)
   ID  Class0  Class1  Class2  Class3  Class4  Class5  Class6  Class7  Class8  \
0   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   
1   1       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       1   
2   2       0       0       1       0       0       0       1       0       0   
3   3       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       1   

   Class9  Class10  Class11  Class12  Class13  Class14  Class15  Class16  
0       1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0  
1       0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0  
2       0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0  
3       0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0
```

Comment: That works, thanks. And how about different way to move values from rows to columns, I mean that if class is for example 5, it should appear in column named Class5. Is it possible to do this in a pretty simple way?

Comment: And same way for all column names? do you need [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) ?

Comment: Yes, thanks, it works fine, but one last issue: How to create columns with for example Class 8, if it isn't in my first dataset? get_dummies create only columns with existing classes.

Comment: then need `df = df.reindex(columns=range(9), fill_value=0)` - it add all missing values

Comment: How can I merging rows after get_dummies operation?

Comment: I think `df = pd.concat([df, df_new], axis=1)` should works.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I got the result, which has two ID column and additional class column. Sorry for my questions, but I'm new in pandas.

Comment: OK, give me some time.

Comment: Glad can help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try

```
df.groupby('ID').Class.apply(lambda x : x.tolist()).to_frame()['Class'].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('Class_').fillna(' ')
Out[602]: 
    Class_0 Class_1 Class_2
ID                         
0       9.0                
1       8.0       6        
2       6.0       2        
3      15.0       1       8
```