# Python, Merging rows with the same id - date but different values in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have selected the rows that are and aren't mentioning 'Korona', and counted them by date. Some of the dates don't have Korona True.
The dataframe looks like:

**TABLE 1**

|  | Published_date | Korona | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 242 | 2020-06-01 | False | 13 |
| 243 | 2020-06-01 | True | 3 |
| 244 | 2020-06-02 | False | 7 |
| 245 | 2020-06-02 | True | 1 |
| 246 | 2020-06-03 | False | 11 |
| 247 | 2020-06-04 | False | 8 |
| 248 | 2020-06-04 | True | 1 |
| 249 | 2020-06-05 | False | 10 |
| 250 | 2020-06-06 | False | 5 |
| 251 | 2020-06-07 | False | 5 |
| 252 | 2020-06-08 | False | 14 |

What I'm trying to do is remove duplicate date rows, but transform the value to another column. So for example this:

|  | Published_date | Korona | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 242 | 2020-06-01 | False | 13 |
| 243 | 2020-06-01 | True | 3 |

Looks like this (after some renaming of columns and adding an Count-All column):

**TABLE 2**

|  | Published_date | Count-NoKorona | Count-Korona | Count-All |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 152 | 2020-06-01 | 13 | 3 | 16 |

And I'm doing that with this code (found it on [Python, Merging rows with same value in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45918559/python-merging-rows-with-same-value-in-one-column) ) :

```
df = df.set_index(['Published_date', df.groupby('Published_date').cumcount()])['Count'].unstack().add_prefix('Count').reset_index()
```

**Problem:**
For some reason after that line of code, my data gets mixed up.

Before that line everything was fine. I had 782 Korona True rows (For a test I only took 'True' rows from the table 1, and summed up the Count of it, and it was correct --> 782). So 782/3443 True.

After the code line I get a sum of 1011/3443.

I'm guessing it takes some wrong values of dates, or it gets mixed up, but I don't know how to fix it, and the data table is too big to found the mistakes manualy to try and understand the problem better.

I would be grateful for any help. (Also sorry if the question doesn't look okay, it's my first :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try using pivot table

```
d = ''' Published_date  Korona  Count
242 2020-06-01  False   13
243 2020-06-01  True    3
244 2020-06-02  False   7
245 2020-06-02  True    1
246 2020-06-03  False   11
247 2020-06-04  False   8
248 2020-06-04  True    1
249 2020-06-05  False   10
250 2020-06-06  False   5
251 2020-06-07  False   5
252 2020-06-08  False   14'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(d), sep='\s+', engine='python')

# pivot the data and reset the index
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Count', index=['Published_date'],
                    columns=['Korona'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0).reset_index()
# rename the columns to what you want
df1.columns = ['Published_date', 'Count-NoKorona', 'Count-Korona']
# sum the values into a new column
df1['Count-All'] = df1[['Count-NoKorona', 'Count-Korona']].sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Published_date  Count-NoKorona  Count-Korona  Count-All
0     2020-06-01              13             3         16
1     2020-06-02               7             1          8
2     2020-06-03              11             0         11
3     2020-06-04               8             1          9
4     2020-06-05              10             0         10
5     2020-06-06               5             0          5
6     2020-06-07               5             0          5
7     2020-06-08              14             0         14
```