# Merging rows in a dataframe by ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large excel document of people who have had vaccinations.
I am trying to use python and pandas to work with this data to help work out who still needs further vaccinations and who does not.

I have happily imported the document into pandas as a dataframe

Each person has a unique ID in the dataframe
However, each vaccination has a separate row (rather than each person)
i.e. people who have had more than a single dose of vaccine have multiple rows in the document

I want to join all of the vaccinations together so that each person has a single row and all the vaccinations they have had are listed in their row.

| **ID** | **NAME** | **VACCINE** | **VACCINE DATE** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | JP | AZ | 12/01/2021 |
| 1 | PL | PF | 13/01/2021 |
| 0 | JP | MO | 24/01/2021 |
| 1 | PL | MO | 24/01/2021 |
| 2 | LK | AZ | 12/01/2021 |
| 3 | MN | AZ | 12/01/2021 |

Should become:

| **ID** | **NAME** | **VACCINE** | **VACCINE DATE** | **VACCINE2** | **VACCINE2 DATE** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | JP | AZ | 12/01/2021 | MO | 24/01/2021 |
| 1 | PL | PF | 13/01/2021 | MO | 24/01/2021 |
| 2 | LK | AZ | 12/01/2021 |  |  |
| 3 | MN | AZ | 12/01/2021 |  |  |

So I want to store all vaccine information for each individual in a single entry.
I have tried to use groupby to do this but it seems to entirely delete the ID field??
Am I using completely the wrong tool?
I don't want to resort to using a for loop to just iterate though every entry as this feels like very much the wrong way to accomplish the task.

```
old_df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name="Report Data")    
new_df = old_df.groupby(["PATIENT ID"]).ffill()
```

I am trying my best to use this as a way of teaching myself to use pandas but struggling to get anywhere so please forgive my novice level.

EDIT:
I have found this code:

```
s = raw_file.groupby('ID')['Vaccine Date'].apply(list)
new_file = pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index).add_prefix('Vaccine Date ').reset_index()
```

I modified this from what seemed to be a similar problem I found:
[Python, Merging rows with same value in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45918559/python-merging-rows-with-same-value-in-one-column)

Which seems to be doing part of what I want. It creates new columns for each vaccine date with a slightly adjusted column label. However, I cannot see a way to do this for both Vaccine date AND Vaccine brand at the same time and without losing all other data in the table.

I suppose I could just do it twice and then merge the outputs with the original dataframe to make a new complete dataframe but thought there might be a more elegant solution.

Comment: "I don't want to resort to using a for loop to just iterate though every entry as this feels like very much the wrong way to accomplish the task." - No, it is the right way. You are trying to restructure the data, which will always need extensive hand-written programs.

Comment: It does seem to be possible as someone else managed to find a way of doing part of what I need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45918559/python-merging-rows-with-same-value-in-one-column

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did for the same problem.

1. Seperated the first vaccination row of every name from the dataframe and saved as a nw dataframe.
2. Create a third dataframe which is initial dataframe minus the new datafame in (1)
3. left join both dataframes and drop NA

   df = pd.read_csv('<your_dataset_name>.csv')

   first_dataframe = df.drop_duplicates(subset = 'ID', keep = 'first')
   data = df[~df.isin(first_dataframe )].dropna()
   final = first.merge(data,how = 'left',on = ['ID','NAME'])

Comment: I like your method. Effectively creating a separate dataframe for 1st vaccine and 2nd vaccine and then merging. This approach may well work. Thank you.